# how to crypt passwords and use it in a function?

Tags: php, mysql, function, md5, crypt

hello i have problems while using crypt function. i would like to check passwords from a database and an entered one.

the problem i have is that when i will enter a password it even will redirect even in case when it is a totally different password? this is strange to me.

so i use this function:

```
function salt_crypt($login_password, $rounds = 7) { 
    $salt = ""; 
    $salt_chars = array_merge(range('A','Z'), range('a','z'), range(0,9)); for($i=0; $i < 22; $i++) { 
    $salt .= $salt_chars[array_rand($salt_chars)]; 
    } 
    return crypt($login_password, sprintf('$2a$%02d$', $rounds) . $salt);
```

i will get the stored password from a function that returns an array:

```
function ab($a){
    global $db;
    $query = $db->query("SELECT col_a, col_b FROM table WHERE Field= '$a' ");
    $check = $query->fetch_assoc();
    return ($check);
}
```

and this will be used in this function:

```
function login($a, $login_password){
    $user_data = user_data($a);
    global $db;
    $uname = sanitize($uname);
    $crypted_password = salt_crypt($login_password);

    if(crypt($user_data['col_b'], $crypted_password) == $crypted_password) { 

        $query = $db->query("SELECT col_a FROM table WHERE Field_a= '$a' AND Field_b = '$crypted_password' ");
        $check = $query->num_rows;
        return ($check == 1) ? true : false;
    }
}
```

this function wil be called and in case of the returning result header with:

```
$login = login($a, $login_password);
        if ($login === false){
            $errors[] = "text";
        } else {
            header('Location: page.php');
        }
```

Comment: Not all code paths return a value in `function login($a, $login_password)`

Comment: Add `return false;` at the end of the function login;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all code paths return a value -> your function will return true, even if the if statement is false. Try it with something like this:

```
function login($a, $login_password){
//All your stuff

     if(crypt($user_data['col_b'], $crypted_password) == $crypted_password) { 
         //Your stuff
     }

    return false
}
```

Comment: okay i did it like that. but i still get the errormessage that the password is incorrect. now i tried to echo the string that should be compared with that from the db $salted = salt_crypt($login_password); and i echoed it and inserted it into the db but still have no access? thanks.

Comment: That's because you seem to generate a random salt. You need a random salt, but you need to generate in ONCE. Not every time. Echo your password, again, you'll se it is different. Just make a global variable `$salt = "Your-random-salt.asdfj;lksajf;klnwer";` and append it to the password string before you encrypt it. (For the salt you can use the password that you echo now, does not really matter, as long as it is random and will never change again) ;)